# Проектная документация на разработку сайта/скрипта/приложения

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос больше к профессиональным программистам, которые заканчивали университет по специальности и работают в данной сфере в крупных компаниях.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли какая-то проектная документация по  программированию сайтов, приложения блок схем и т.д.?

Например, есть техническое задание от заказчика. Мне нужно разработать логику работы сайта/модуля/скрипта  и реализовать всё на PHP. Для себя и для заказчика, наверное, было бы логично описать, как это будет работать, какие данные будут получены от пользователя, каким образом они будут обрабатываться сервером и т.д. Или нарисовать схему для наглядности.

Как вообще это делается?

Спасибо!

Comment: Это называется методология разработки. Сейчас в мире используется несколько различных методологий, но большинство склоняется, к так называемой, гибкой (agile) методологии.

Comment: При чем здесь методология разработки @MikhailVaysman когда спрашивают о документировании логике работы модуля/приложения? Здесь будет более актуальным разработка схем, описывающих эту самую логику, течение информации и наброски для пользовательского интерфейса - https://pro-prof.com/archives/1462. Единственное что нужно принять к сведению, это то что у различных методологий разработки существуют отличные друг от друга требования к документации.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, MikhailVaysman Спасибо за ответы! А есть ли какие-нибудь примеры уже реализованных проектов?

Comment: А вы выбрали для себя ты самую методологию, по которой будете работать? Тогда по ней и нужно искать примеры документации...

Comment: @DanielProtopopov от методологии сильно зависит как, когда и какие артефакты разработки будут порождены командой. Например, в waterfall все требования должны быть представлены заказчиком до начала разработки и менять их нельзя.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Не выбрал, потому что в впервые слышу про эти методологии. Наверное, нужно перелопатить кучу документации, чтобы понимать с чем сравнивать. Я думал, что возможен один подход к управлению проекта. Или простые классические схемы реализации.

Comment: @Pavel если у вас нет опыта, то вам нужен консультант или вы рискуете завалить проект.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, возвращаясь к свои предыдущим проектам, не всегда сразу врубаешься, что там происходит. Поэтому для меня было бы проще взглянуть на схему или прочитать пояснительную записку, чтобы понимать как это работает. Потому и хотелось бы привести всё к одному виду, чтобы было проще.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, сам к этому и пришёл уже, поняв что не было выбрано методологии.

Comment: @Pavel, читайте на https://rsn81.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/user-guide-agile-development/  - при разработке документация как таковая делится на техническую, архитектурную и функциональную. В простых проектах док-я сводится к документации сервиса, функции или классов - при создании чего-то более объемного придётся описывать (при необходимости) остальное как например польз-й интерфейс, схему БД и др.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Спасибо!

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Спасибо!

Comment: То что вы хотите и называется ТЗ. А то что вы получили от заказчика видимо им не является, а является только набором требований.